# It's possible to create a new array from object properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I got this

```
{
 content: "item1",
 img: urlImg1
},
{
 content: "item2",
 img: urlImg2
}
```

I need to output something like this

```
newArray = [item1, urlImg1, item2, urlImg2]
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

Comment: Is the current format an array of objects? asking this since you did not put them between square brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the input as an array of objects, you can make use of `Array.reduce` and `Object.values`.

```js
const data = [{ content: "item1", img: "urlImg1" }, { content: "item2", img: "urlImg2" }];

//loop through the array of objects using `Array.reduce`
const values = data.reduce((res, obj) => {
  //Get the values of the object using `Object.values`
  //And spread and push to the accumulator i.e., `res` array
  res.push(...Object.values(obj));
  return res;
}, []);

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the original array:

```js
const array = [{
   content: "item1",
   img: 'urlImg1'
  },
  {
   content: "item2",
   img: 'urlImg2'
  }
];

const newArray = array.map(obj => obj.content);

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
const arr = [{
   content: "item1",
   img: 'urlImg1'
  },
  {
   content: "item2",
   img: 'urlImg2'
  }
];

const mapToNewArray = (arr) => {
    let newArray = [];
    arr.forEach(a => { 
        newArray = newArray.concat(Object.values(a));
    }); 
    return newArray; 
}

newArray = mapToNewArray(arr);
```